# How to make second tab can open when the first tab is already filled and submitted

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter and bootstrap,so please consider my mistakes. I have a three tabs in my page, all tabs contains form that must to be filled. And the second tab only open when the first tab already submitted and so on. Can you to solve that problem?

Here's my code :

```
<div class="nav-tabs-custom">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#dtpasien" data-toggle="tab">Data Pasien</a></li>
        <li><a href="#dtmds" data-toggle="tab">Data Medis</a></li>
        <li><a href="#odontogram" data-toggle="tab">Odontogram</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="active tab-pane" id="dtpasien"></div>
        <div class="active tab-pane" id="dtmds"></div>
        <div class="active tab-pane" id="odontogram"></div>
    </diV>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont use ajax, I use manual @tejuc

Comment: By submitted do you mean filled in because I assume the form doesn't get submitted till all the information in all the tabs is filled in. Further, if you were using Ajax this would be rather easy.